# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.4

I can't read the word Curaçao from a text file.  What am I doing wrong?

I have written a text file that contains the word "Curaçao".  The encoding on the editor (vim) is latin1.

This python program reads the file:

```
import sys

with open ('foo.txt', 'r', encoding='latin1') as f:
    print('f:', f.encoding)
    print('stdout:', sys.stdout.encoding)
    for i in f:
        print(i)
```

And when I run it I get this...

```
sundev19:/home/jgalloway12/code/wdPhone $ python3 CountryFix.py
f: latin1
stdout: 646
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CountryFix.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(i)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the file's contents in binary.

```
0000000: 4375 7261 e761 6f0a                      Cura.ao.
```

EDIT: The "real" problem I am trying to solve here is reading an Excel 2010 exported CSV which contains country names.

Fixed the file to be encoded in Latin1.  Program now prints locale.

Comment: @BobDylan UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: try `print(i.encode('latin1'))`, or even better - 'utf-8'

Comment: There should be hundreds of cases of this error here. Have you tried searching the web for the error message?

Comment: Note that your hexdump shows the _UTF-8_ encoding of `Curaçao`. `binascii.hexlify(u'Curaçao'.encode('utf8'))` gives `43757261c3a7616f`; `binascii.hexlify(u'Curaçao'.encode('latin1'))` gives `43757261e7616f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't the file, but the output stream.

For whatever reason, python has detected your stdout encoding as US-ASCII when you really want something more (utf-8, latin1, etc.).

Your options are:

Trick it into believing a different encoding (on linux you can do this with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, however I assume you're on windows and I don't recall how to trick python on windows in this way :)).

Write your response to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='latin1') as f:
    ...
```

Or write to the stdout bytestream:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(i.encode('latin1'))
```

Comment: I'm on Solaris!  Putty is set for remote character set UTF-8 and echo $LANG returns `C`.

Comment: I think in your case if you invoke as `LANG=en_US.latin1 python3.4` (if your file is actually latin1) should work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are printing the lines and python `print` function doesn't use of the encoding of `open()` function it tries to encode your string with it's default encoding which is ASCII. So you need to define a costume encoding for your unicode when you want to print it.

You can use [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method with a proper encocding for print.

Comment: `.encode` won't help you with print: >>> print('\u2603'.encode('utf-8'))
b'\xe2\x98\x83'

Comment: Based on what is that character and what is its proper encoding and what is your default encoding the result will have a lot of possibility!

Comment: print() only accepts text in python3, you're probably thinking of the python2 behaviour

Comment: No i mean this :`>>> print('\u2603'.encode('utf-8'))
b'\xe2\x98\x83'
>>> print('\u2603'.encode('utf-16'))
b'\xff\xfe\x03&'
>>> print('\u2603'.encode('utf-32'))
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x03&\x00\x00'
`

Comment: sure, but writing a python repr to a csv file is pretty useless :)